# Can't run the music/video on Windows 10 through the use of Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-10, alarm, audio-player, taskscheduler

I was planning on using the Task Scheduler as an alarm on my laptop, I created a task that would run a music/video (loud music videos for example) file on WMPlayer that I selected and act as an alarm.The problem is, every time the task ran at the specified time, before running the music file, it would ask me what program that I should use; (Notepad, Paint, Windows Media Player, WordPad, etc.). When I clicked the WMPlayer, it said that it couldn't find the file, and when I tried using the program Notepad it also said that it couldn't find the saved file. Supposedly the path name must be like this: ***"C:\Users\PCNAME\Music\Canon Rock - Jerry C (Studio Version).mp3"***, but whenever I tried to run it using Task Scheduler and choose Notepad/WordPad, the path name will be cut off, leaving the first word after the ***"Music\ "*** like this: ***"C:\Users\PCNAME\Music\Canon "***. I don't know if there's something wrong with my Task Scheduler or if its the file itself. Note that I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: This is the wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead.. This site is for programming related questions, not general OS support.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the same feature in Windows 7 and it worked fine but after I upgraded to Windows 10 it was broken somehow.

**The fix:**
I no longer run the file as "path\music.mp3" but instead I trigger a .bat file to play the song with the default player. The .bat file content should be like this:

**start C:\Users\PCNAME\Music\"Canon Rock - Jerry C (Studio Version).mp3"** <- please note that the "" around the audio file may be very important for it to work if there's white spaces in the song name.